# Trouble with composite foreign keys in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

there! I have a failing foreign key constraint in sqlite3 and I really have no idea why. I'm using a composite foreign key as discribed here (http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_composite) and a "normal" foreign key.

Here are my schemas:

```
sqlite> .schema sources
CREATE TABLE sources(
    source_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    source_type INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER,
    month INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(source_id),
    UNIQUE(title)
);
sqlite> .schema author_aliases
CREATE TABLE author_aliases(
    author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    alias_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    forenames VARCHAR(128),
    surname VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(author_id, alias_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES authors(author_id),
    UNIQUE(forenames, surname)
);
sqlite> .schema alias_source_relations
CREATE TABLE alias_source_relations(
    source_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    alias_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(source_id, author_id, alias_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(source_id) REFERENCES sources(source_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(author_id, alias_id) REFERENCES author_aliases(author_id, alias_id)
);
```

Here is the data the foreign key is referring to:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sources WHERE source_id='Allen1980';
Allen1980|0|The definition of electronegativity and the chemistry of the noble gases|1980|
sqlite> SELECT * FROM author_aliases WHERE author_id=1 and alias_id=1;
1|1|Leland C.|Allen
sqlite> SELECT * FROM authors WHERE author_id=1;
1|Leland Cullen|Allen
```

And here is my insert:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO alias_source_relations VALUES(1, 1, 'Allen1980');
Error: foreign key constraint failed
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Marian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check column order!

```
INSERT INTO alias_source_relations VALUES('Allen1980', 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Inserting the data in the correct order works like charm ;-) I used a python script to insert a lot of data, which succeed in wrong order. Apparently the python script failed to turn on FOREIGN_KEYS PRAGMA, otherwise is couldn't have the data inserted. When I tried manually to add some data in the same order the python script did, it faild. I would have never thought that my python script managed to insert the data in the wrong order. I really need to check my python code rigorously.

Comment: Should I delete this question? I think there is not much to learn from my stupid question, is it?

Comment: Isn't a stupid question, it's a bug! Maybe someone, sometime get same problem and seeing this answer realize his own bug.

Answer (score 4):

The order of the inserted values does not match the column order as defined in the table schema.

It's safer and also more descriptive to include the column names. Like this, the order does not need to match the one in the table schema and someone who does not know the table schema by heart still understands the command:

```
INSERT INTO alias_source_relations (source_id, author_id, alias_id)
    VALUES ('Allen1980', 1, 1);
```